# App Store submission: minimum SDK version

Tags: ios, app-store

Apple released iOS 5.1 and the developer bits yesterday. One change is that the new stuff is Lion only. Currently OSX Lion isn't yet rolled out, and to have an exception, I must tell IT why. I think I have read you must submit with the latest SDK version. To apply for the exception I would need to send a link to the documentation. Sadly enough, I can't find where I have read this. Maybe, this has changed. Can someone help me out of the tone of material and point me to the place?

Nailed down: If I'm using iOS 5 SDK and not iOS 5.1 SDK to develop new apps, can I further submit apps to the store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the iOS 5.1 SDK release notes, which can be found here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5_1/_index.html

You'll see that within the first couple paragraphs of the introduction is this quote:

> With this software you can develop applications that run on iPhone,
>   iPad, or iPod touch running iOS 5.1. You can also test your
>   applications using the included iOS Simulator, which supports iOS 5.1.
>   iOS SDK 5.1 **requires a Macintosh computer running OS X 10.7 (Lion)**.

Comment: I have read this. But my problem slightly differs: I'm going to get Lion only if I absolutely need to (ie I can't submit apps without having iOS 5.1 SDK installed). I'm editing my question to make that more clear.

Comment: Yes, you can continue to submit apps built with the iOS 5 SDK and XCode 4.2. I think it's even possible to submit apps built with XCode 3.X for older iOS SDK's. As long as you can submit it via Application Loader or Xcode and they test it and something built for older SDK's works fine under the latest iOS, you should be good to go.

Comment: So I do not need to install Lion and iOS 5.1 and happily move on until Lion gets rolled out?

Comment: Yes, that's my impression of the current state of affairs.